# Android studio - mantener conectado servicio a mysql

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio, android-service

quisiera saber como puedo mantener un servicio conectado a mysql desde un servicio android y extraer informacion. Hasta el momento hago una HttpURLConnection hacia un archivo php que hace el proceso, pero solo se ejecuta el servicio una sola vez, luego de cerrar la aplicacion el servicio no se sigue ejecutando, aparece corriendo pero no hace nada.

```
public String verificarDatosNuevos(String us){
    String parametros = "user="+us;
    HttpURLConnection conexion = null;
    String result ="";
    try{
        URL url = new URL(urlb+"nuevosDatos.php");
        conexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conexion.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conexion.setDoOutput(true);
        Scanner inStream = new Scanner(conexion.getInputStream());
        while(inStream.hasNextLine()){
            result += (inStream.nextLine());
        }
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    return result.toString();
}

public int cantMsg (String user){
    int resp = 0;
    try {
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(verificarDatosNuevos(user));
        if(json.length() > 0){
            resp = json.length();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resp;
}
```

Utilizo esas dos funciones para extraer los datos y en el servicio hago lo siguiente:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    verificarNuevo();
    onDestroy();
    return START_STICKY;
}
public void verificarNuevo(){
    Thread tr = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int r = db.cantMsg(userFy);
            if(r > 0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Tienes "+r+" mensaje(s)...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
    tr.start();
}
```

En el archivo php retorno un json array para saber cuantos mensajes no se han visto aun:

```
<?php

$usuario = $_POST['user'];

$cnx = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bddayton","root","root");
$res = $cnx->query("select * from newmsg where user = '".$usuario."' and condicion_visto = 0 ");

$datos = array();
foreach ($res as $row){
    $datos[]=$row;
}

echo json_encode($datos);
?>
```

Lo que no logro es que me muestre el Toast, simplemente se destruye y se inicia infinitamente sin hacer nada.

Lo que quiero es que cuando haya un registro nuevo(la tabla tiene un campo de condicion donde 0 es no visto y cualquier otro dato es visto), la aplicacion me alerte de ese registro. Ayuda por favor!!.

Comment: ¿Que tienes en onDestroy de tu servicio?

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(this,SensorService.class);
        startService(i);

Comment: Ahora veo!, no es necesario este método, el método se inicia y aunque lo mandes a background si tienes definido START_STICKY ,  no necesitas iniciarlo en onDestroy(), este iniciara nuevamente. Como ejemplo: https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Music-in-Background

Comment: gracias, eso me ayudo bastante. Sabes algo en cuanto a lo ultimo? de como hacer una conexion con la base de datos?

Comment: lo que vi es que por ejemplo, la musica la reproduce bien, pero un toast no lo continua mostrando, solo una vez.

Comment: Te sugiero verificar el LogCat , lo de la base de datos no muestra el Toast porque no encuentra resultados, no se cumple  if(r > 0){ ...

Answer (score 0):

Veo que tu servicio tiene definido `START_STICKY`

> **Service.START_STICKY** : recrea el servicio si la aplicación se
>   destruye.

pero el problema es que estas llamando `onDestroy()` al iniciar el servicio, este método se llama al detener el servicio, si lo estas sobre escribiendo en realidad no es necesario llamarlo.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    verificarNuevo();

   // onDestroy(); //*INCORRECTO

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: el problema es que, por ejemplo quisiera mostrar un Toast mientras se ejecute el servicio, solo lo hace una vez, cierro la aplicacion y no se vuelve a ejecutar.